# SPEND LESS MONEY alphametic

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, alphametic

The well-known verbal arithmetic problem

```
    S E N D
+   M O R E
-----------
  M O N E Y
```

explains (or at least it did the first time I knew about it) the story of a student who send a telegram to his father, asking for more money, and asks to fill in each letter with a different digit in order to figure out how much the student was asking for.
What's not so broadly known is the answer his father gave:

```
  S P E N D
-   L E S S
-----------
  M O N E Y
```

Even though, the father was not as good as the son with verbal arithmetics and by mistake made an impossible one.

***Could you prove that the rest he proposed is impossible?***

*Of course, feel free to solve the first verbal arithmetic (which can be solved indeed), but the real question is about the impossibility to solve the second one.*

Note: The first verbal arithmetic problem is only provided for flavour, and the same letter does not necessarily represent the same number between both equations.

Comment: I've seen a different formulation of this one before. Good puzzle though.

Comment: With the constraints stated here, the rest is possible, as 00000-0000=00000. You should explicitly state the constraints on the original problem, assuming they're the same for the new one. In particular, does each letter have to represent a different digit?

Comment: @JasonC edited to clarify different letters are different numbers

Comment: @JoeZ. The OP has added the constraint. Without the constraint, it's not impossible (e.g. wrt your answer, consider if N and S are both 0).

Comment: Hmm. That's a good point. I suppose 00000 - 0000 = 00000 would be a correct solution to both in that case.

Comment: I heard the response as SPEND-LESS=SON which also fails.

Comment: @RossMillikan Because SP = 10 and L = 9, but since S = 1 in the third column, you can't have E - E = S?

Comment: @JoeZ:  Right you are

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If $E - E = N$ in the third column, then $N$ is either $0$ or $9$.

Suppose $N$ was $0$; then you'd have to borrow 1 in the fourth column to subtract $S$ from $0$, but $N$ can only be $0$ in the third column if you don't borrow anything.

Similarly, suppose $N$ was $9$; then you'd have to have borrowed 1 in the fourth column. But $9$ minus anything never borrows, so that case is impossible as well.

Comment: This logic works for any positive integer base, not just decimal numbers.  N must either be 0 or (base -1), and won't work for the same reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more non-technical:

> Give each word a value of (+1) or (-1) for relevance to their meaning
>
> **Spend = -1
>
> Send = +1
>
> More = +1
>
> Less = -1**
>
> Therefore [Send + more]: **(+1) + (+1) = Money**
>
>  and [Spend - Less]: **(-1) - (-1) = Money**
>
>  meaning that money must equal both 2, and 0. (Which is not possible)
>
>  The Dad should have said 
> |Spend + Less = Money|
>
> **|(-1) + (-1)| = |-2| = 2**

Comment: That's a rather easy way to solve it, provided both cryptograms were true at the same time. Even though, as the last note on the question stated, they are completely independent.

Comment: @AlbertMasclans That is with dealing with letters, not words ;D